# Dynamically add properties to `dynamic` type

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, system.reflection, dynamic-typing

If I have a list of property infos, and the instance of the object they came from, how can I create another object containing those properties and values?

e.g.

```
public dynamic Sanitize<T>(T o)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(o, null))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var type = o.GetType();

    var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    dynamic sanitized = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        var name = propertyInfo.Name;
        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(o, null);

        // Add this property to `sanitized`
    }

    return sanitized;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast the ExpandoObject to an `IDictionary<string, object>` and then manipulate it as such at runtime to add properties:

```
var sanitized = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
    var name = propertyInfo.Name;
    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(o, null);
    sanitized.Add(name, value);
}
```

Comment: How do I reference properties from this? `sanitizedType.PublicBoolTrue` and `sanitizedType["PublicBoolTrue"]` both throw exceptions.

Comment: Where do you need to reference those properties? Inside the method? I would rather split this into 2 methods. The first one will populate the ExpandoObject with a dictionary as shown in my answer and then call the method and after that you will be able to reference those properties like you shown assuming you have stored the result of this method call into a variable of dynamic type. Otherwise if you need to reference the property inside the same method you could use `sanitized["PublicBoolTrue"]`.

Comment: The purpose is for logging.  The input object `o` can have properties attributed with `[NotLoggable]`, so this method is supposed to return an object containing only 'loggable' public properties.

Comment: So, the properties would be referenced by whatever logger(s) the resulting object is passed to.  They might just serialize it or might do some aggregation or formatting first.

Comment: The properties will be added dynamically. So if you attempt to access them, or serialize the resulting object it will just work out of the box.